# Installing Windows 2008 - Hangs During Expanding Files

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 2008 R2 from a USB stick and it hangs during the expanding files, generally in 23% if I install Standard and 16% if it's Enterprise.

I checkdisk the USB it's fine, tried 3 times to ensure that files are not corrupted. Did memory check.

Even more interesting I tried to install Windows 7 and very same behaviour happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change the memory? Did you try a different USB stick? Is the hard drive ok?

Comment: HHD was working fine a in a different system, don't have another USB Stick but it works perfectly fine and installed many systems with it before, I had 4GB of RAM uninstalled 3 of them just to decrease the risk, don't have any other to change.

Answer (score 1):

As expected it was HDD, even though checkdisk and everything else looked fine when I changed the HDD it worked just fine.

Comment: This is one of those occasions where I use the "format" option rather than "quick format" in setup.  I've discovered drives that I thought were ok that ended up being faulty.  Better to find out right at the start before relying on it for a server (or a workstation).